# Inverse Text in Excel

Tags: excel

ABC-123 in 1 column and I need to have it show 123-ABC in another (for multiple rows and text), what's the best way to do it?

```
ABC-123 
DEF-456
```

would like such sets of data to be copied to another colum, but reverse:

```
123-ABC
456-DEF
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to create a function that does that.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming data in `A2` then you can use this formula in `B2` to swap the data before the hyphen with the data after, **regardless of the length of each part**

```
=MID(A2&"-"&A2,FIND("-",A2)+1,LEN(A2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to

```
=CONCATENATE(RIGHT(B24; FIND(" - ";B24)-1); " - "; LEFT(B24; FIND(" - ";B24)-1);)
```

my data was stored in B24